# I'm stuck. trying to create dynamic Peg Solitaire

Tags: arrays, vb.net, grid

I've not made much of a start on this, at all... However, before I can begin the actual game functions... I need to be able to load a handful of controls dynamically to populate an area on the window.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim b As Button

Public col As Integer
Public row As Integer
Public counter As Integer = 1

Dim grid(,) As Integer = {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}


Private Sub MyButtons()
    Dim temp As String = ""
    For row = 0 To 8
        For col = 0 To 3
            temp = "This is number: " & grid(row, col)
        Next
        MessageBox.Show(temp)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MyButtons()
End Sub
End Class
```

The controls in particular would be picture boxes, laid out in a 9x9 grid. Displayed in the code above is just something I've been using to try to work out how it works.

I would like it so based upon a numerical value within an array's value, 0 would display nothing, 1 would display an empty peg hole and 2 would display a peg.

Once I've figured out how to load everything in a grid specifically using an array, I'll be able to sort the rest myself.

... And yes, this is for an assignment and I've honestly looked everywhere. I'm not sure what the grid method is called using the integer, so google is just not useful at this point

So does anyone have some knowledge to impart on me? Thank you!

Comment: fair play for admitting its part of an assignment. but its not clear what exactly you are asking?

Comment: How can I instantiate the array, and then use each individual element to use as a reference for a button... so I can then refer to it in order to check for valid moves etc.